# Oracle SQL Question about grouping and getting latest record

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi suppose i have the following dataset:

```
first, last, height, phone, email,date
Test, Test1, ,,,1/1/2001
Test, Test1, ,,,1/1/2004
Test2, Test2,5 4,,,1/1/2007
Test2, Test2,5 4 ,,,1/1/2010
Test2, Test2,5 4 ,,,1/1/2003
Test3, Test3,,123456789,,1/1/2020
Test3, Test3,,123456789,,1/1/2001
Test4, Test4,,,test@test.com,1/1/2013
Test4, Test4,,,test@test.com,1/1/2014
Test4, Test4,,,test@test.com,1/1/2018
```

I know i can get the count by doing having count(first) > X but my goal is to get the newest record so the final result should be:

```
first, last, height, phone, email,date
Test, Test1, ,,,1/1/2004
Test2, Test2,5 4 ,,,1/1/2010
Test3, Test3,,123456789,,1/1/2020
Test4, Test4,,,test@test.com,1/1/2018
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out a query to get the wanted results.

Thanks,

Comment: There are already good answers, so you will be able to solve your issue. I just would like to mention that using SQL key word as column names is not recommended. So if you can change them in your DB, this could make your life easier (rename as example "date", "first", "last" to "datec", "firstc" and "lastc" or similar).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT first, last, height, phone, email,date from (
    SELECT 
        first, last, height, phone, email,date,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by first order by date desc) as num
    from YOUR_TABLE
) A where num = 1
```

Comment: This works, but you have a typo: You wrote ROW_ROWNUMBER, correct would be ROW_NUMBER. Could you please fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `MAX` with `GROUP BY` from your sample data

```
SELECT first, last, height, phone, email,MAX(date)
FROM T
GROUP BY first, last, height, phone, email
```

or you can try to use `fetch first`

```
select *
from T
order by row_number() over (partition by first, last, height, phone, email order by date desc)
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

Comment: Thank you, well done. I just added a fiddle to show it's working: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=399889d70e2c4a309cf8ce98e3488a15. You could add an ORDER BY first in your first query.